# Apple Pay suppression message scares our users

Tags: mobile, ios, apple, ux-writing

I'm working on a mobile app that uses NFC to connect to specific devices. For iOS phones, we are required to [suppress the Apple Pay interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkpasslibrary/1617078-requestautomaticpasspresentation), because otherwise the Wallet app will show up when presenting the phone to a device with our app open.

If we do this, an iOS phone will show the following (unchangeable) system pop-up to inform the user:

[image: iOS system pop-up]

This pop-up is causing some concern at our end users. Two of the most common comments we get:

1. **Payment? What payment? I thought this app was free!**
   Yes the app is free, and no we do not take any form of payment from you. We simply suppress the Wallet app when you use our app.
2. **My Wallet app will not work? But I use that a lot!**
   The Wallet app only doesn't work if you have OUR app open. Any other time, it still works

My first solution would be a better pop-up text, but since we cannot change it, we need to think of something else.

What can i do to make it more clear that we are not asking for payments, OR completely blocking the iOS wallet app?

Comment: Hi Dennis, what's the moment when the warning from Apple shows up? Does it happen every time the app opens, at key moments when the app is in use, or other times?

Comment: The moment we set the flag "requestAutomaticPassPresentationSuppression". It's a one time pop-up that Apple devices show when this method is called. But the Apple pop-up message isn't really clear to our users, so basically... i need to explain what the Apple pop-up means.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think the suggestion by @oamandawi is correct - add a message before the pop-up, and in a FAQ. Since users often blow through onboarding without reading, it's probably best to still have a message right before the Apple pop-up appears, annoying as it is to create.

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak about completely blocking the iOS wallet app (maybe a question for Stackoverflow?). Regarding making it clear that you are not asking for payments, you can add a page explaining that, which shows up before the pop-up. Another way could be to have an FAQ section on your app that explains this popup.

Comment: We now have an onboarding step that explains that Apple Wallet is suppressed during the usage of the app BEFORE the pop-up shows. It's just stupid that I have to explain iOS system pop-ups